# Getting error in JCommander, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in java

Tags: java, maven, jcommander

Hey I am getting following complete error on my console, while trying to run my project.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/JCommander
        at ro.uaic.info.VRPRunner.main(VRPRunner.java:42)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.beust.jcommander.JCommander
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

I have added jcommander dependency in pom.xml file

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
            <version>1.48</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Can you help me what should i do to resolve this error?

Comment: atleast first check if maven was able to resolve the dependency, you can also check if the jar was downloaded.

Comment: Yes, jars have been created. But then too it is giving this NoClassDefFoundError